# How to create stored procedure using cursor to move data from one table to another table with validation ( Mysql)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

I have to move data from resource table to event table to remove resource table.
Consider, Table schemas as follows,
mysql> desc event

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| event_id        | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| path            | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

mysql> desc resource;

```
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| resource_id        | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| jcr_id             | varchar(500) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

event path contain jcr_id or resource_id, if it contain jcr_id then entry from resouce table else update event path value with jcr_id and then delete.

Consider following Psuedo code while iterating every resource_id,

```
 result = select event_id from event where path=_resource_id;
 if result is empty 
   delete from resource where resource_id= _resource_id;
 else 
   update event set path=jcr_id where event_id= result;
   delete from resource where resource_id= _resource_id;
```

Comment: The first step in moving data is learning how to format the data in your question.

Comment: yes, Working on it

Comment: Please explain the requirement with suitable examples.

Comment: @HatimStovewala you can consider Psuedo code as example, i wanted to iterate resource table with every resource_id with query "select event_id from event where path=resource_id" id i found any result for this query then i have to update path value with jcr_id and delete entry from resource table.

Comment: Did my answer helped?

Comment: No, actually i want to perform this procedure on 10 Million+ entries. i am looking for more optimized answer using cursor or temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `new_procedure` ()
BEGIN
    declare row_min int;
    declare row_max int;
    declare resource_id int;

    select 1, max(resource_id)
    into row_min, row_max
    from resource;

    while row_min <= row_max
    do
        select resource_id into resource_id
        from resource
        where resource_id = row_min;

        -- Iterating for every record. Add your update code here.

        set row_min = row_min + 1;
    end while;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```